# Dependend DropDown using Codeigniter, No Jquery nor Ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make subsector dependent on sector, i am not using jquery nor ajax

This is my Controller

```
    <?php
        /*

        */
        if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class Salesforce extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->database();
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                //load the employee model
                $this->load->model('sf_model');
            }
            //index function
            function index()
            {
                //...


                $data['sector'] = $this->sf_model->get_sector();
                $data['subsector'] = $this->sf_model->get_subsector();
                $data['type'] = $this->sf_model->get_type();

                //set validation rules

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_name', 'Account Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_only_space');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_web', 'Website', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_type', 'Type', 'callback_combo_check');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_sector', 'Sector', 'callback_combo_check');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_subsector', 'Sub Sector', 'callback_combo_check');


                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                    //fail validation
                    //echo 'Validation failed';
                    //print_r($_REQUEST);
                    $this->load->view('sf_view', $data);
                    //
                }
                else
                {
                    //pass validation
                    $data = array(

                        'a_name' => $this->input->post('a_name'),
                        'a_website' => $this->input->post('a_web'),
                        't_id' => $this->input->post('a_type'),
                        's_id' => $this->input->post('a_sector'),
                        'ss_id' => $this->input->post('a_subsector'),
                        'a_billingStreet' => $this->input->post('a_billingStreet'),
                        'a_billingState' => $this->input->post('a_billingState'),
                        'a_billingZip' => $this->input->post('a_billingZip'),
                        'a_billingCountry' => $this->input->post('a_billingCountry'),
                        'a_billingCity' => $this->input->post('a_billingCity'),
                        'a_phone' => $this->input->post('a_phone'),
                        'a_mobile' => $this->input->post('a_mobile'),
                        'a_fax' => $this->input->post('a_fax'),


                    );
                    //print_r($data);
                    //exit;

                    //insert the form data into database
                    $this->db->insert('account_info', $data);

                    //display success message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">New Account Created</div>');
                    redirect('salesforce/index');
                }
            }




            //custom validation function for dropdown input
            function combo_check($str)
            {
                if ($str == '-SELECT-')
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('combo_check', 'Valid %s Name is required');
                    return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }

                //custom validation function to accept only alpha and space input
            function alpha_only_space($str)
            {
                if (!preg_match("/^([-a-z ])+$/i", $str))
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_only_space', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets or spaces');
                    return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }



        }
```

This is my Model

```
<?php
        class Sf_model extends CI_Model
        {
            function __construct()
            {

                parent::__construct();
            }


            function get_sector()
            {
                $results = $this->db->select('s_id, s_name')->from('account_sector')->get()->result();

                $s_id = array('-SELECT-');
                $s_name = array('-SELECT-');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
                {
                    array_push($s_id, $results[$i]->s_id);
                    array_push($s_name, $results[$i]->s_name);
                }
                return $sector_result = array_combine($s_id, $s_name);
            }
            function get_subsector()
            {
                $results = $this->db->select('ss_id, ss_name')->from('account_subsector')->get()->result();

                $ss_id = array('-SELECT-');
                $ss_name = array('-SELECT-');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
                {
                    array_push($ss_id, $results[$i]->ss_id);
                    array_push($ss_name, $results[$i]->ss_name);
                }
                return $subsector_result = array_combine($ss_id, $ss_name);
            }
            function get_type()
            {
                $results = $this->db->select('t_id, t_name')->from('account_type')->get()->result();

                $t_id = array('-SELECT-');
                $t_name = array('-SELECT-');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
                {
                    array_push($t_id, $results[$i]->t_id);
                    array_push($t_name, $results[$i]->t_name);
                }
                return $type_result = array_combine($t_id, $t_name);
            }
        }



>
```

This is my View

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>SalesForce | Edit / New Account Details</title>
            <!--link the bootstrap css file-->
            <link href="<?php echo base_url("bt/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- link jquery ui css-->
            <link href="<?php echo base_url('bt/css/jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!--include jquery library-->
            <script src="<?php echo base_url('bt/js/jquery-1.11.3.js'); ?>"></script>
            <!--load jquery ui js file-->
            <script src="<?php echo base_url('bt/js/jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>"></script>

            <style type="text/css">
                .colbox {
                    margin-left: 0px;
                    margin-right: 0px;
                }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 well">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <?php
                    $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "accounts", "name" => "accounts");
                    echo form_open("salesforce", $attributes);?>
                    <fieldset>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_name" class="control-label">Account Name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_name" name="a_name" placeholder="Enter Account Name" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_name'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_name'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_web" class="control-label">Website</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_web" name="a_web" placeholder="Enter Website" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_web'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_web'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_type" class="control-label">Type</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">

                                    <?php
                                    $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "a_type"';
                                    echo form_dropdown('a_type',$type,set_value('a_type'),$attributes);?>
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_type'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_sector" class="control-label">Sector</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">

                                    <?php
                                    $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "a_sector"';
                                    echo form_dropdown('a_sector',$sector,set_value('a_sector'),$attributes);?>
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_sector'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_subsector" class="control-label">Sub Sector</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">

                                    <?php
                                    $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "a_subsector"';
                                    echo form_dropdown('a_subsector',$subsector, set_value('a_subsector'), $attributes);?>

                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_subsector'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_billingStreet" class="control-label">Billing Street</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_billingStreet" name="a_billingStreet" placeholder="Enter Billing Street" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_billingStreet'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_billingStreet'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_billingState" class="control-label">B-State/Province</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_billingState" name="a_billingState" placeholder="Enter State/Province" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_billingState'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_billingState'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_billingZip" class="control-label">B-Zip/Postal</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_billingZip" name="a_billingZip" placeholder="Enter Zip/Postal" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_billingZip'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_billingZip'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_billingCountry" class="control-label">Billing Country</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_billingCountry" name="a_billingCountry" placeholder="Enter Billing Country" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_billingCountry'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_billingCountry'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_billingCity" class="control-label">Billing City</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_billingCity" name="a_billingCity" placeholder="Enter Billing City" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_billingCity'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_billingCity'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_phone" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_phone" name="a_phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_phone'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_phone'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_mobile" class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_mobile" name="a_mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_mobile'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_mobile'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row colbox">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="a_fax" class="control-label">Fax Number</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                    <input id="a_fax" name="a_fax" placeholder="Enter Fax Number" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('a_fax'); ?>" />
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('a_fax'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 text-left">
                                <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert" />
                                <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: We'll be here when you add the "This is my question" part.

Comment: can't understand @Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
   $data['sector'] = $this->sf_model->get_sector();
   if(isset($data['sector'])&&$data['sector']!="")
   $data['subsector'] = $this->sf_model->get_subsector($data['sector']);
```

Model, In model pass sector as parameter to get_subsector function and then during database select please pass it to where or as per your requirement you may procced.

Also Please avoid array_push() function in loops, use $ss_id[] = $results[$i]->ss_id; because it is much faster.

```
function get_subsector($sector)
            {
                $results = $this->db->select('ss_id, ss_name')->from('account_subsector')->get()->where($sector)->result();

                $ss_id = array('-SELECT-');
                $ss_name = array('-SELECT-');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
                {
                    array_push($ss_id, $results[$i]->ss_id);
                    array_push($ss_name, $results[$i]->ss_name);
                }
                return $subsector_result = array_combine($ss_id, $ss_name);
            }
```

Comment: That wasn't my question SIR. @sashant

Comment: Thank you for response, but you mentioned " I want to make subsector dependent on sector, i am not using jquery nor ajax ". So my interpretation was the subsector data depends on sector data. So could you please clarify your requirement more, If there is any misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

> using some js and ajax

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#a_subsector').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#a_sector').change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/salesforce/fill_ss',
                    type:'post',
                    data: {sector:$('#a_sector').val()},
                    success:function(result){
                        $('#a_subsector').removeAttr('disabled');
                        //$('#a_subsector').(result);
                        document.getElementById('a_subsector').innerHTML=result;
                    }
                });
                });
        });

</script>
```

> Adding a Function to controller

```
function fill_ss()
{
    $this->sf_model->get_subsector();

    $sector = $_POST['sector'];
    $data = $this->sf_model->matching($sector);
    //print_r($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$data[$i]->ss_id.'">'.$data[$i]->ss_name.'</option>';
        //echo '<option value="'.$data[$i]->ss_id.'"></option>';
        //array_push($t_id, $data[$i]->t_id);
        //array_push($t_name, $data[$i]->t_name);
    }

}
```

> Model

```
function view_accounts()
{
    $results = $this->db->select('a_name,t_id,a_website,a_billingStreet,a_billingZip,a_billingCountry,a_billingCity,a_phone,a_mobile')->from('account_info')->get()->result();
    return $results;
}
function matching($match)
{
    $results =$this->db->select('ss_id,ss_name')->from('account_subsector')->where('s_id',$match)->get()->result();
    return $results;

}
```